# Rename file after (last) directory

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I am trying to rename files in my bash to their latest file name. The structure is as follows:

```
directories..../Test1/abc.txt
directories..../Test2/abc.txt
directories..../Test3/abc.txt
```

I want to end up with

```
directories..../Test1/Test1.txt
directories..../Test2/Test2.txt
directories..../Test3/Test3.txt
```

Right now I am stuck here:

```
pathname=/mnt/grid/*

for file in /mnt/grid/*/*.txt; do
    mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename ${pathname}.txt)"
done
```

Comment: hot tip - throw `echo` before your `mv` to debug before you commit to actually doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the name of the directory containing a file run `basename "$(dirname "$file")"`. For example:

```
$ file=/tmp/foo/bar.txt
$ basename "$(dirname "$file")"
foo
```

This way there's no need for `pathname`, and the loop body can simply be

```
echo "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "$(dirname "$file")").txt"
```

(Replace `echo` with `mv` if this looks right.)

Comment: thanks so much. this did the trick!! :) saved me a lot of time!